# How to Connect DataGridView in C# To an SQL Database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, datatable

I'm trying to pass data from DataGridView to a Database SqlClient I opened especially for this. When the program runs, it tells me this error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I made a form with 2 buttons, one for adding data to the DataGridView (works fine) and another one to pass the data to a database table.
the not working button's code is this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=.;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
        con.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
    }
```

What can I do to fix it?
I tried choosing a data source to the DataGridView but it still didn't work out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem is with the connection, it has nothing to do with the datagrid. I don't know the ins and outs of `AttachDbFileName` because I've never found it useful, but the error message is reasonably clear. Is it really your intent to use an auto-named database?

Comment: The code snippet you provided is adding data from database to datagridview. Please provide code which sends the data from grid to database, which  is causing error to you.